# ERROR Matplotlib installing PLEASE HELP ME?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to install matplotlib like this `python -m pip install -U pip python -m pip install -U matplotlib` and it gave me this Error Code :
`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`
Can you help me ?

Comment: Why not using `python -m pip install matplotlib` or just `pip install matplotlib`

Comment: Probably you tried to install on 3.9 which isn't yet supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pip install matplotlib` in the terminal (Unix/Linux), cmd or Powershell in Windows.